# @Endpoint and @Transactional on the same class using Spring-ws library

Tags: spring, spring-ws

I am trying to implement a web-service endpoint which would be transactional because I don't want to create a special "worker" class with transactional methods. I'm using Spring-ws library together with Spring framework.

Here is my class definition:

```
@Endpoint
@Transactional
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyEndpoint implements ApplicationContextAware { ... }
```

Notice that I explicitly specified proxying method to force using CGLIB.

Also notice that my class implements some interface(s), so by default Spring uses JDK dynamic proxy unless another proxying method is specified. This kind of proxies is not appropriate in my case.

The problem begins on application deployment when `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` class starts working. It collects names of all Spring beans with `@Endpoint` annotation. My endpoint class is counted twice with names "`myEndpoint`" and "`scopedTarget.myEndpoint`". This duplication causes `ApplicationContextException` with message "Cannot map endpoint [...] on registration key [...]: there's already endpoint [...] mapped".

Question: how can I make my endpoint class being transactional?

Comment: What about http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You might write your own `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` extension and override the `initApplicationContext` method. There you can check for the `scopedTarget.` prefix to filter out unwanted beans:

```
public class ProxiedBeanAwareEndpointMapping extends PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping {

    @Override
    protected void initApplicationContext() throws BeansException {
        initInterceptors();
        String[] beanNames = getApplicationContext().getBeanNamesForType(Object.class);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            if (!beanName.startsWith("scopedTarget.")) {
                Class<?> endpointClass = getApplicationContext().getType(beanName);
                if (endpointClass != null && AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(endpointClass, getEndpointAnnotationType()) != null) {
                    registerMethods(beanName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Or you can use the [open session in view](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) approach so you don't need to proxy your `@Endpoint`s.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I actually did. But it seems like a hack rather than correct solution.

Comment: It definitely is a hack :).

Comment: I'm afraid it can fail with some later Spring version.